# Detect if JavaFX Node appears under cursor

Tags: java, javafx, frontend

There is a list of messages in chat.

User can pin questions which moves them to the top of the list.
I need to detect if the pinned question appears under the cursor or not.

Currently, I'm using setOnMouseEntered to display some options when the cursor enters the question:

```
question.setOnMouseEntered((MouseEvent e) -> {
        unpinAndAnswerOptions.setVisible(true);
    });
```

This is how it looks like if the cursor enters the pinned question from outside.
[Correctly displayed]

[image]

This is what happens when the pinned question appears right under the cursor.
[Uncorrectly displayed]

[image]

I know it's possible to just detect if the question is at the same index after moving and use that to display the options, but I'm curious if there is some other way.

Comment: Any chance you could [edit] your question and post a [mcve] so that I can reproduce your problem and subsequently debug your code?

Comment: The problem was with the ListView I was using to reorder the questions. `listView.refresh()` solved my issue. But I'll keep that in mind when asking questions in the future. Thanks :)

Comment: repeating: refresh is more often than not an indication of something wrong ;)

Comment: Thanks for edit -> I could not add the images directly into the post since I'm a new user with low rep.

Comment: What we have here isnt a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case of update view use [`Platform.runLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html);

Comment: This would've solved my problem if I used ListView properly -> thanks to you I discovered how it should be done.

listView.refresh() solved it

Comment: seemingly needing to use refresh is a strong indication of something fundamentally wrong ;) As is runlater .. there are corner-cases for both. Which might or not be the case of the OP, no way to tell without details.

Comment: @kleopatra it's very much possible that there is something wrong. It is my first project ever using JavaFX and Spring. I first used VBox, but discovered that displaying everything in ListView is much better if I want to reorder the Nodes. Each node has event handler like the one in the question above. I didn't understand why it doesn't count as entering the node when the node "teleports" under the cursor. Apparently it does when I refresh the listView. I don't know what question exactly I should ask, because I don't know how it should be done properly. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: _what question exactly I should ask_ that's part of the reason why providing  a [mcve] (as suggested in question) is a good idea :)